# Javascript, using Highcharts to display a chart of rankings with JSON Data

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am trying to use javascript Highcharts to display a chart of rankings from JSON data.  I can't seem to get the chart to display.

This is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'drawing',
            zoomType: 'x',
            width: 900,
            height: 222
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled:true      
    },
    title: {
        text: url+' - '+keyword
    },
    credits: {
        text: '****',
        href: 'http://***/'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%b %e '   
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        //min: 1,
        allowDecimals: false,
        reversed: true,
        ///: .2,
        //maxPadding: .2,

        title: {
            text: 'Rankings'
        }
    },],

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{}]
};  

var url =  "http://*******/chart.php";
    $.getJSON(url,  function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(arrayID,group) {
            $.each(group.data, function(id,val) {
            arg = val[0].replace(/Date.UTC\((.*?)\)/, '$1').split(',');
            var timestamp = Date.UTC.apply( null , arg );
            date=new Date(timestamp);
            data[arrayID].data[id][0] = timestamp;
            });
        });

        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });                          
});
```

Our PHP Script gives us this JSON:

```
[{"name":"Google Rank","data":[["Date.UTC(2013,04,05)","23"],["Date.UTC(2013,04,04)","23"],["Date.UTC(2013,04,03)","22"],["Date.UTC(2013,04,02)","24"],["Date.UTC(2013,04,01)","26"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,31)","24"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,30)","24"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,29)","25"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,28)","25"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,27)","25"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,26)","26"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,25)","25"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,24)","24"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,23)","-"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,22)","10"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,21)","10"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,20)","10"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,19)","10"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,18)","10"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,17)","10"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,16)","9"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,15)","9"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,14)","9"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,13)","9"],["Date.UTC(2013,03,12)","9"]],"visible":"true","pointInterval":"86400000","showInLegend":"false"},{"name":"Bing Rank","data":["Date.UTC(2013,2,9)",9],"visible":"true","pointInterval":"86400000","showInLegend":"false"}]
```

Note the JSON data represents numbers as strings which could be a problem.

PHP Code which generates the JSON data:

```
$googledata = array();
while($gkdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($keywordquery)){
    $explodedate = explode("-", $gkdata['date']);
    $year = $explodedate[0];
    $month = $explodedate[1];
    $day = $explodedate[2];    
    $googledata[] = array(
        "".$year.",".$month.",".$day."",  
        $gkdata['grank']     //$gkdata['grank'] should be a number, but is sometimes a dash so it's cast to an accommodating datatype: string.
    );
}

$chartdata = array(
    array(
        "name" => 'Google Rank',
        "data" => $googledata,
        "visible" => 'true',
        "pointInterval" => '86400000',
        "showInLegend" => 'false',
    ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Bing Rank',
        "data" => array(
            'Date.UTC(2013,2,9)', 
            9
        ),
        "visible" => 'true',
        "pointInterval" => '86400000',
        "showInLegend" => 'false',
    )
);
```

The Highcharts won't display anything other than the chart itself with no data.  The `Date.UTC(2013,03,12)` is supposed to go on the X-Axis & the number next to it is supposed to be the rank number.  Can anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The chart takes data as [x,y].  You just need to reverse the order of your data to ['value',datestamp'] if you want the date to be on the y axis.

Edit:

I am not sure from the text what the problem you are having is, but one problem that will arise from your code is that your number data values are being returned as strings, in quotes.

You will need to cast them as integers in your php before json encoding in order for them to come through unquoted, as integers.

You should be seeing an error from this: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14

Comment: Sorry, I edited it I accidently said Y-Axis. I want the datastamp to be on the X-Axis. Apologies.

Comment: The issue what I am having is that the data isn't being displayed in the chart. Google Rank is suppose to be one title, with a line of data like "2013, 04, 05" then the 23, then that should loop through them all. However it won't display anything other than the chart itself with no data.

Comment: that will be the result of the problem that I describe in the edit to my answer above.  return the numbers as numbers, and you should be all set.

Comment: Well again that is another issue, for some reason it is automatically adding the quotes:

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message you are getting.  Part of the problem is you are coding blind, not seeing what the javascript interpreter has to tell you.  Would you expect a mechanic to work blindfolded?

Comment: Sorry. Look at the main topic now, please :)

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `$gkdata['grank']` to always return a number, it sometimes returns a dash `-`.  The Array Object is using the datatype which best represents the data, and it chooses string.  If you want to force it as int, you'll have to use a data structure that only allows integers to be put in it.  Then it will puke when you try to put in a dash, which it should be doing, because how do you plot a DASH on a chart?

Had you taken off your blindfold, and looked at the error HighCharts returned to you, you would see this:

**Highcharts Error #14 String value sent to series.data, expected Number**

This happens if you pass in a string as a data point, for example in a setup like this:

```
series: [{
    data: ["3", "5", "1", "6"]
}]
```

Highcharts expects the data values to be numbers. The most common reason for this is that data is parsed from CSV or from a XML source, and the implementer forgot to run parseFloat on the parsed value.

For performance reasons internal type casting is not performed, and only the first value is checked (since 2.3).

So fix your code to make grank always a number.  HighCharts won't plot strings for performance reasons.

Comment: Please, only one question per Stack Overflow page.  This website is a repository for useful answers to common questions people have, as it stands this question isn't a very good one because it is highly localized.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask  If you ask more over localized questions your reputation will go down and you won't get any attention.  So improve your reputation, then add new questions in a new page.